# Compare pandas dataframes, capture data from other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am not exactly sure how to phrase this question, but let me give you an example. I have 2 pandas dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = [['tom', '1000', 50], ['bill', '1001', 45], ['mike', '1002', 30], ['joe', '1003', 35]]
data2 = [['1000-000', 'New York'], ['1001-000', 'Los Angeles'], ['1005-000', 'Chicago'], ['1006-000', 'Atlanta']]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['name', 'id', 'age'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['id #', 'city'])
```

Both dataframes have an `id` column, which I want to compare. But I need to shorten df2's id column in order to do so:

```
df2['id shortened'] = df2['id'].str[:4]
```

Now I compare the `id` column from df1 and the `id shortened` column from df2:

```
df3 = df1[df1['id #'].isin(df2['id shortened'])]
```

If I print df3, this is the result:

```
   name    id  age
0   tom  1000   50
1  bill  1001   45
```

This is close, but what I REALLY want is this:

```
   name    id  age       id #
0   tom  1000   50   1000-000
1  bill  1001   45   1001-000
```

The `id #` is what is important, but I am not sure how to include that in the results when comparing the two dataframes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can do:

```
df1.merge(df2.assign(id=df2['id #'].str.extract('^(.*)-')),
          on='id',
         )
```

Output:

```
   name    id  age      id #         city
0   tom  1000   50  1000-000     New York
1  bill  1001   45  1001-000  Los Angeles
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to use is the `DataFrame.merge()` method:

```py
>>> df2['id'] = df2['id #'].str[:4]
>>> df3 = df1.merge(df2, on='id')
>>> print(df3)

   name    id  age      id #         city
0   tom  1000   50  1000-000     New York
1  bill  1001   45  1001-000  Los Angeles
```

You need to name the `id shortened` column the same as the column you want to merge on in `df1`, which in this case would be `id`. If you don't want additional columns like `city`, you can simply drop them afterwards using `DataFrame.drop('city', axis=1)`.